# how to debug wcf web service in visual studio express?

Tags: wcf, debugging, visual-studio-express

I have developed the WCF web service in vb.net in visual studio 2010 express edition. also deployed t locally as of now. since VS Express does not support Unit testing i cannot test web service. where as restricted using framework like NUnit. how should i test my web service and debug it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WCF Test Client(found at this location -

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\

).

Bind the wcf TEST client process for debugging. From VS go to debug -> Attach to process -> wcfTestClient.exe.

Then execute the method from test client and you would be able to debug the service code

Comment: worked without attach process. What i did: run the web service app, copy the url and add its web reference locally to web application . which allows me to directly enter to the wcf web methods for debugging. also WCF Test client worked for me